# Receive "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" when attempting to fill NaN with values from other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, fillna

I am working with one data frame in pandas only.  This error does not occur when I perform the following on a subset of this data frame (6 rows with NaN in some).  And it does exactly what I needed done.  In this case all the NaN in the 'Season' column got filled out properly.

Before:
[image: subset data frame before]

Code:

```
s = df.set_index('Description')['Season'].dropna()
```

```
df['Season'] = df['Season'].fillna(df['Description'].map(s))
```

After:
[image: Afterwards:]

Great!  This is what I want to happen, one column at time.  I worry about the other columns later.

But then I try the same code above on the entire data frame which is over 5000 rows long, then I get the error stated above in the title, and I am unable to pin point it to a specific row(s).

What did I try:
I removed all non-ascii characters, and these special characters: ', ", and # from the strings in the 'Description' column which sometimes has 50 characters including non-ascii and the three specific characters that I removed.

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')

df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace('"', '')

df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace("'", "")

df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace('#', '')
```

But the above did not help, and I still get the error. Does anyone have additional troubleshooting tips, or know what I am failing to look for?  Or ideally a solution.

The code with subset DataFrame and main DataFrame are isolated.  So I am not mixing and using the 'df' and 's' interchangeably.  I wish that was the problem.

Recall the subset data frame above where the code worked perfectly.  Through process of elimination I discovered that when the subset data frame has one extra row - total of 8 rows, the code still works as expected.  But once the 9th row is entered, the I get the error.  I can't figure out why.

[image: DF with 8 rows Before the code]

Then the code:
`s = df.set_index('Description')['Season'].dropna()`
`df['Season'] = df['Season'].fillna(df['Description'].map(s))`

And the data frame is updated as expected:

[image: DF with 8 rows after the above code is ran]

But when the 9th row added then the code above does not work:

[image: DF with 9 rows - Before the code]

[image: DF with 9 rows - After the code is ran]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't show full error but there is word `Index` so your problem has nothing to do with column `Description`. Probably you have two rows with the same index - but it needs `uniquely valued index` - so you may need to `reset_index()`

Comment: Bartłomiej "furas" Burek  Thank you for replying to my problem ticket.  But I cannot see any evidence of two rows having the same index.  The main data frame has 8656 rows and the index column (first column of data frame in bold) is numbered from 0 to 8655.  when I do df.info(), the above is confirmed as the first 4 columns have 8656 non-null values.  So I cannot see having two rows with same index number.

Nevertheless, I tried inserting .reset_index() but I get a new error that says:  "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects".

Comment: Recall the subset data frame above where the code worked perfectly.  Through process of elimination I discovered that when the subset data frame has one extra row - total of 8 rows, the code still works as expected.  But once the 9th row is entered, the I get the error.  I can't figure out why.

Comment: maybe split line in smaller parts to see which one makes problem - first only `df['Description'].map(s)`, next `df['Season'].fillna(df['Description'].map(s))` - both without `df['Season'] = `. And it should also display values in columns so you can see if they create correct values - maybe one of them need `reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks again Bartłomiej "furas" Burek for your trouble shooting tips.  I tried what you said, and just running:

df['Description'].map(s) fails when the data frame has 9 rows, and shows the same error message that I have documented above.  But it runs successfully when the data frame has 8 rows.  I also tried:

df['Description'].map(s).reset_index() 

and I get the same error with the data frame that has 9 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered how to solve the problem by adding .drop_duplicates('Description') and therefore modifying:
`s= df.set_index('Description')['Season'].dropna()`

to

`s= df.drop_duplicates('Description').set_index('Description')['Season'].dropna()`

Comment: But doesn't this mean that you lose data?